# How to draw circular arrow and multiline text below a node in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I have a beamer frame as shown below. It draws two nodes of `tikzpeople` and then arrows between them. However, I want to draw two additional things. First I want to have multiline text below the left icon, and to draw an annotated circular arrow on top of right icon. What I want to achieve is shown in the figure below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Tables
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    matrix,
    overlay-beamer-styles,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    tikzmark
}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\tikzset{hl/.style={
    set fill color=red!80!black!40,
    set border color=red!80!black,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Security Notion - IND-CPA-FE}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\node[name=a,charlie,minimum size=2cm] (A) at (0,0) {$(\mathsf{msk},\mathsf{mpk}) \gets \mathsf{Setup}(1^\lambda, \mathcal{F})$};
\node[name=b,devil,minimum size=2cm] (B) at (10,0) {};
\uncover<2->{\draw[->] (1.5,1.25) -- (8,1.25) node[midway, above]{$\mathsf{mpk}$};}
\uncover<3->{\draw[->] (8,0.5) -- (1.5,0.5) node[midway, above]{$x_0^*, x_1^*$};}
\uncover<4->{\draw[->] (1.5,-0.25) -- (8,-0.25) node[midway, above]{$c^* \gets \mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{mpk}, x_b^*)$};}
\uncover<5->{\draw[->] (8,-1) -- (1.5,-1) node[midway, above]{$b'$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the multiline part: `\node[name=a,charlie,minimum size=2cm, text width=4.5cm] (A) at (0,0) {$(\mathsf{msk},\mathsf{mpk}) \gets \mathsf{Setup}(1^\lambda, \mathcal{F})$ \linebreak some text};`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz This leaves a lot of empty space between the icon and the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard loop and a custom loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[charlie, minimum size=2cm, align=center] (A) at (0,0) {$(\mathsf{msk},\mathsf{mpk}) \gets \mathsf{Setup}(1^\lambda, \mathcal{F})$\\Text also here} edge[loop above] node {Text} ();
\node[devil, minimum size=2cm] (B) at (5,0) {};
\draw[->] (B) to[out=45, in=90, looseness=5] node[above right]{Text} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two person figures with loops above]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Tables
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    matrix,
    overlay-beamer-styles,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    tikzmark
}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\tikzset{hl/.style={
        set fill color=red!80!black!40,
        set border color=red!80!black,
    },
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Security Notion - IND-CPA-FE}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
            \node[name=a,charlie,minimum size=2cm] (A) at (0,0) {$(\mathsf{msk},\mathsf{mpk}) \gets \mathsf{Setup}(1^\lambda, \mathcal{F})$ \\Hello is anybody out there ?};
            \node[name=b,devil,minimum size=2cm] (B) at (10,0) {};
            {\draw[->] (1.5,1.25) -- (8,1.25) node[midway, above]{$\mathsf{mpk}$};}
            {\draw[->] (8,0.5) -- (1.5,0.5) node[midway, above]{$x_0^*, x_1^*$};}
            {\draw[->] (1.5,-0.25) -- (8,-0.25) node[midway, above]{$c^* \gets \mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{mpk}, x_b^*)$};}
            {\draw[->] (8,-1) -- (1.5,-1) node[midway, above]{$b'$};}

            \path[->] (B) edge [loop above] +(0,0);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Tiks has a has a nice `loop` option: https://tikz.dev/library-automata

So I added  `(B) edge [loop above] +(0,0);`

And the multiline text is easier:
`\\Hello is anybody out there ?}`

You can also add the option `[text width = 50]` to get the desired effect.

There are of course other ways to achieve this.

Comment: Can you move the loop to be on the side (like in the picture above)? And also add a text on top of the arrow?

Comment: yes and yes
https://tikz.dev/library-edges#pgf.loop:above

Comment: All the links I provided give an example of how to do it.

Comment: `loop above` is not from `automata`, so you do not need `\usetikzlibrary{automata}`

Comment: good correction. thank you.

Comment: @anis Please also don't try to add tags based on the tools you use (or think you use) in your answer. Tags should describe the problem, not the solution.